# Android: how to update in the PreferenceActivity a setting modified in another activity?

Tags: android, preferences

I have a PreferenceActivity, but some of the settings can be modified from another Activities also. But when a user modifies a setting from another activity, and then goes to the PreferenceActivity this change is not reflected there.

How can I make the change made from outside be reflected in the PreferenceActivity?

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);
    }
}
```

and here is the code from another activity

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.getApplication());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("my_setting", true);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: QA discussed here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619724/accessing-another-activitys-preferences

Comment: the better matching question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466189/reload-preferences-in-preferenceactivity-on-resume

Comment: another useful post: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=184679960D7135D361B76DB5827C8393?recipeId=561&recipeFrom=ViewTOC